# Relation between measure and outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and $\mu^*$ be an outer measure on $P(S)$ defined by $$\mu^*(A) = \inf \{\sum_{i = 0}^\infty \mu(E_i) \ | \ (E_i)_{i = 0}^\infty \textrm{ is a measurable cover of }A \}$$

I want to prove that for all $A \subseteq S$, there is a measurable set $E$ such that $A \subseteq E$ and $\mu^*(A) = \mu(E)$. As hint I have to prove first that $\mu^*(A) = \inf \{ \mu(E) \ | \ E \in \Sigma, A \subseteq E\}$.

For any measurable cover $(E_i)$ of $A$, we have that $\bigcup E_i$ is measurable and contains $A$, and furthermore $\mu(\bigcup E_i) \leq \sum \mu(E_i)$, so indeed $\inf \{ \mu(E) \ | \ E \in \Sigma, A \subseteq E\} \leq \mu^*(A)$. For the other direction it suffices to show that $\mu^*(A)$ is a lower bound for $\{\mu(E) \ | \ E \in \Sigma, A \subseteq E\}$, but I am stuck on proving that.

Assuming the statement from the hint, we just need to show that $\{\mu(E) \ | \ E \in \Sigma, A \subseteq E\}$ contains its infimum. We can either explicitely construct an $E$ such that $\mu(E)$ is its minimum, or think of some topology on $\Sigma$ that makes $\{E \in \Sigma \ | \ A \subseteq E\}$ compact and $\mu$ continuous, but I don't get further than that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu^{*}$ is monotone: $\mu^{*}(E) \leq \mu^{*}(F) $ if $E \subseteq F$. Hence $\mu^{*}(A)$ is a lower bound for $\{\mu(E): R \in \Sigma, A \subseteq E\}$.

There exist a sequence $(E_n)$ in $\Sigma$ such that $A \subseteq E_n$ for all $n$ and $\mu(E_n) \to \mu^{*}(A)$. Verify that $\mu^{*}(E)=\mu (E)$ where $E=\cap_n E_n$.